# Video stabilization: extracting the transformation rules used by ImageAlign

Tags: image-processing, video

Imagine that I have a real life video, with all the artefacts coming from real life, and also from video compression, etc, and that I can edit this video, with filters and cropping, in such a way that I can improve the success of `ImageAlign` as an image stabilizer. How can I align/stabilize the original video, using the transformation rules identified for the edited one?

(I think that) This is not a question on how to recreate the ImageAlign function, from other functions belonging to the same family (`FindGeometricTransform`, etc).

(I'm sure that) this is not a question on what Options would make it work better on the specific example I putted together (unless there's an option that gets these transformation rules out..., and that I completely missed)

Let's start by creating a shaky film:

```
film = Rasterize /@ Table[
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None],
  Blue, 
  GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[{-4, -4, 0}], 
   Table[RotationTransform[
     i*Pi/2 + angle, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}], {i, 4}]],
  Red, 
  GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[{-4, -4, 0}], 
   Table[RotationTransform[i*Pi/2, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}], {i, 
     4}]]},
 Boxed -> False, 
 ViewVector -> {5 {Pi, Pi/2, 2}, {0 + RandomReal[], 
    0 + RandomReal[], 0}}, ViewAngle -> Pi/5],
{angle, 0, 2 Pi/4 - Pi/32, Pi/32}
];

ListAnimate[film]
```

[image]

And now, let's try to unshake it:

```
filmSteady1 = ImageAlign[film[[1]], #, TransformationClass -> "Rigid"] & /@ film;
```

(**First side note:** if we do not `Rasterize` it before, interestingly, it still works, but there's probably a bug in the internals of the ImageAlign function, or in compile, since I keep receiving the message: "CompiledFunction::cfn: Numerical error encountered at instruction 8; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>"). I'm not expert enough to understand its origins. Can someone try to catch this one, so that it gets reported?

```
ListAnimate[filmSteady1]
```

[image]

Very bad...

Now, lets try `ImageAlign` with a very simple filter added (again, this is an example; one can think of masks, two completely different videos, coming from two different recording technologies, etc):

```
infoFilm = ColorReplace[#, Blue -> White, 0.3] & /@ film;
filmSteady2 = ImageAlign[infoFilm[[1]], #, TransformationClass -> "Rigid"] & /@ infoFilm;


ListAnimate[filmSteady2]
```

[image]

Much better! How can I then apply to the target/original video, the identified transformation rules?

**Second side note:** if instead of using "Blue->White", you just write "Blue", the results from `ImageAlign` are not the same... Shouldn't there be a way for `ImageAlign` to keep the transparent information? (I imagine this is coming from the background option, but it makes more sense on image borders, than in the middle of the image).

**Third side note:** Once the transformation rules are listed, it is possible to imagine a multitude of techniques that would probably be more adapted to a video: comparing each image/frame to the previous one (in time), and then, pre-combining the transformation rules all together, before processing the image; analyze just every n frames, and analytically determine halfway transformations to apply to the non analyzed frames (so to go faster); determine a smooth transformation "path", obeying to some spline rule or similar; etc...

Comment: I imagine that `ImageAlign` uses `ImageKeypoints` and `FindGeometricTransform` internally. Can't you do the same, in order to get access to the transformation?

Comment: @OleksandrR. the options seem to indicate that ImageAlign has extra tricks available.

Comment: Really? Maybe in version 10. I only have version 9 and the options there are the same. Would be worth trying the `ImageAlign` options as undocumented possibilities for `FindGeometricTransform`, perhaps.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Version 10 introduced as methods: Keypoints, MeanSquareGradientDescent, Fourier, FourierBlurInvariant. Indeed, the FindGeometricTrasnformation has {"ImageAlign",method}, which should do the trick. I will try it, and post the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Following the comments from Oleksandr R.:

```
aux = Import["input.gif"];
i1 = ColorReplace[aux[[1]], Blue -> White, 0.3];
ImageTransformation[#,
 FindGeometricTransform[ColorReplace[#, Blue -> White, 0.3], i1,
  TransformationClass -> "Rigid", Method -> {"ImageAlign"}][[2]],
 DataRange -> Full, Background -> White, Masking -> All] & /@ aux
```

[image]

Lets see if the result is exactly the same (with `ImageSubtract`):

[image]

A few remarks are in order:

- the result is not 100% the same. **should this be reported?** (is the `TransformationClass` being passed to the `ImageAlign` method?)
- you will notice that I used the `FindGeometricTransform` with the two first arguments inverted in respect to (what is my reading from) the documentation: "The function trfun can be applied to the positions pts2 to align them with the positions pts1". **Is this a bug?**
- is it possible to completely remove the black line at the image limits (why doesn't `Background` work to the full extents? Is there a better way of doing it, or **would this be an "improvement" request**?