# FindGeometricTransform (still) can't reproduce ImageAlign results

Tags: image-processing

I'm aligning two images for purpose of some DIC calculations. A smaller bitmap should be found into the bigger one:

[image: smaller]  [image].

`ImageAlign` works solid here:

```
resImg1 = ImageAlign[bigger, smaller, TransformationClass -> "Rigid", 
          Method -> {"Keypoints", {"ORB", "KAZE"}}];
Manipulate[ImageCompose[bigger, {resImg1, a}],{{a, 0.5}, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```

but formally the same:

```
    trn = FindGeometricTransform[ bigger, smaller, 
          TransformationClass -> "Rigid", 
          Method -> {"ImageAlign", "Keypoints", {"ORB", "KAZE"}}];
resImg2 = ImagePerspectiveTransformation[smaller, trn[[2]], 
          DataRange -> Full];
Manipulate[ImageCompose[bigger, {resImg2, a}], {{a, 0.5}, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```

fails sadly.

How should I then extract the transformation function or matrix achieved by the `ImageAlign` procedure?

Comment: You should say how it fails. Both fail for me because the method options are invalid , but I suspect that may be a version issue. (10.1 here). If I remove the `{"ORB", "KAZE"}` both "work". They give different but both reasonable results.  (You ultimately have a uniqueness problem and have demonstated why DIC patterns should be random )

Comment: @george2079 - I was surprised by links number limitation. Results from `ImageAlign` are indeed reasonable:  http://imgur.com/a/2tlGx, but from `FindGeometricTransform` are not: http://imgur.com/a/lwUeQ. Also, the smaller bitmap seems to have enough distinctive features to be correctly aligned - consider the dark, slighty oblique line repeated on both images. My Mathematica version 11.1.1.0, but similar issue is circling around for older versions too: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81427/video-stabilization-extracting-the-transformation-rules-used-by-imagealign